# Linq Select New Property IF Date is Max()

Tags: vb.net, linq, max, anonymous-types

I am trying to create an attribute "Level" that will be set to 0 if the records CompletedDate is the largest/max in the entire result set, otherwise set it to 1.  I need to know what "Level" it is for output purposes so i can properly render the nested divs.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
From g In pciData.AsEnumerable() _
Order By (g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) Descending _
Select _
    Name = IIf(g.SmartForm.FormName Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.FormName.ToString()), _
    Level = IIf( _ 
    iif(Date.Parse(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) = "GET MAX DATE OF RESULT SET HERE", 0, 1)
```

**ANSWER**

```
Level = IIf(Date.Parse(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) = _ 
Date.Parse(pciData.Max(Function(m) m.SmartForm.CompletedDate)), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I'd calculate that date before these calls and use it in the IIf. Something like this `Dim maxDate As DateTime = pciData.AsEnumerable().Max(Function(s) s.CompletedDate)`

Comment: Thanks @Saragis I will try that if all else fails, but I really want to have it in the same query.  Even if its not in the select clause. I updated my question .

Comment: Well it's certainly also possible to use `pciData.AsEnumerable().Max(Function(s) s.CompletedDate)` inside of your IIf. I just don't know how that will affect performance compared to what I suggested (might have an effect).

Comment: @Saragis i was actually going to ask that, i will test and document my findings on it, if there are in differences that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

(Untested freehand typed code..may contain typos)

```
From g In pciData.AsEnumerable() _
Let MaxDate = g.max(function(f) f.CompletedDate) _
Order By (g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) Descending _
Select _
Name = IIf(g.SmartForm.FormName Is Nothing, "", g.SmartForm.FormName.ToString()), _
Level = IIf( _ 
iif(Date.Parse(g.SmartForm.CompletedDate) > MaxDate, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I put mine up at the exact time :)  this would work too just the same i think.